# Calculating overall grade from a partial grade

Tags: arithmetic

If I have a $76\%$ grade but I didn't do a project that was worth $15\%$ of my grade, what would my overall grade be?

Please I need to know and I suck at math.

Comment: This all depends on the class grading criteria.  We can't really be sure of what your overall grade would be since you didn't give enough information about other 85%.

Comment: Depends on the instructor, and university policy. I would give a grade of Incomplete.

Comment: This question makes me cry.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that this 76% is the totality of the 85% of your grade. Then your total grade is:
$$
76\%\cdot0.85+0\%\cdot 0.15=64.6\%.
$$

You're gonna want to do that assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If you didn't do $15\%$ of the work, what percentage did you do?  Presumably you got $76\%$ of that, so multiply.  I hope this is homework, not your position in the class.

Comment: Since it is final week for most colleges, I am guessing this is not homework, but rather OP's grade...

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't do an assignment worth 15% of your grade (i.e. you get a zero on that assignment), that leaves (100-15)=85%.

If out of those 85% (0.85), you got 76% (0.76), then:
$$ Your\;Total\;Grade = 0.85 *0.76 = 0.646 $$
So your overall score in the class is 64.6%.